# How Can i move the hitbox of a static sprite, but also not have the object affected by gravity, in the Phaser Framework?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

So I have a moveable static sprite in phaser,
Basically I want the object and its hitbox to move and be collideable, while also not being affected by gravity

when i make a static body,

```js
this.marker = this.physics.add.staticSprite(0,0, "tileSnap");
```

the hit box stays at (0,0) while the rest of the sprite moves

when i make it a normal physics sprite, its starts dropping due to gravity

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the answer in this discourse thread,

its like

```js
platforms = this.physics.add.image(370, 430, ‘platform’).setImmovable(true)
platforms.body.setAllowGravity(false);
```